# Handling where the user goes when clicking on a notification?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, swift5

I have several different types of notifications, all of which should take the user to a different view controller when the notification is clicked on.

How should this be handled (I'm using Swift 5, by the way)? From my research, I see that people tend to present a new view controller in the `AppDelegate`'s `didReceive` function, but doing all the logic, for several different view controllers, all in the `AppDelegate` seems wrong. Is this really the right way of doing it?

Further, I'm using Firebase to send messages to the device from the backend. I have a separate class, `FirebaseUtils`, where I handle all logic for the data that's passed along. Would it be better to present the view controller from here? If so, how would I do that without the root view controller?

Answer (score 1):

I typically set up something along these lines (untested):

- Create a `NotificationHandler` protocol for things that may handle notifications

```
protocol NotificationHandler {
    static func canHandle(notification: [AnyHashable : Any])
    static func handle(notification: [AnyHashable : Any], completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
}
```

- Create a `notificationHandlers` variable in AppDelegate and populate it with things that may want to handle notifications.

```
let notificationHandlers = [SomeHandler.self, OtherHandler.self]
```

In `didReceive`, loop over the handlers, ask each one if it can handle the notification, and if it can, then tell it to do so.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    guard let handler = notificationHandlers.first(where: 
        { $0.canHandle(notification: userInfo) }) {
    else {
        return
    }

    handler.handle(notification: userInfo, completionHandler: completionHandler)
}
```

This approach keeps the logic out of the AppDelegate, which is correct, and keeps other types from poking around inside the AppDelegate, which is also correct.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm still not sure how I would present a view controller from the NotificationHandler itself.

Answer (score 0):

would something like this work for you?

```
struct NotificationPresenter {
   func present(notification: [AnyHashable: Any], from viewController: UIViewController) {
      let notificationViewController: UIViewController

      // decide what type of view controller to show and set it up

      viewController.present(notificationViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
}
```

```
extension UIViewController {
   static func topViewController(_ parentViewController: UIViewController? = nil) -> UIViewController {
      guard let parentViewController = parentViewController else {
         return topController(UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!)
      }

      return parentViewController.presentedViewController ?? parentViewController
   }
}
```

```
let notificationPresenter = NotificationPresenter()

func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], 
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
   notificationPresenter.present(userInfo, from: UIViewController.topViewController())
}
```